# issue with calculation fo azimuth

Tags: postgis

I want to calculate azimuth between two points so I did it this way like described here : 
[How to calculate the angle at which two lines intersect in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25126/how-to-calculate-the-angle-at-which-two-lines-intersect-in-postgis)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS angletmp;
CREATE TABLE angletmp AS
WITH 
intersections AS
(
    SELECT
        ST_Transform
        (
            (ST_Dump
            (   
                ST_Intersection
                (
                    a.geom, 
                    b.geom
                )
            )).geom,
            3785
        )
        AS intersection,
        a.geom as geom1,
        b.geom as geom2,
        a.id as id1,
        b.id as id2
    FROM 
        pipe a, 
        pipe b
    WHERE
        ST_Intersects
        (
            a.geom,
            b.geom
        )
),
buffers AS 
(
    SELECT
        intersections.intersection,
        ST_ExteriorRing
        (
            ST_Buffer
            (
                intersections.intersection
                , 10
            )
        )
        AS extring,
        ST_Transform(intersections.geom1,3785) AS geom1,
        ST_Transform(intersections.geom2,3785) AS geom2,
        intersections.id1,
        intersections.id2
    FROM 
        intersections
),
points AS
(
    SELECT 
        ST_GeometryN
        (
            ST_Intersection
            ( 
                buffers.extring, 
                buffers.geom1
            )
            , 1
        )
        AS point1,
        ST_GeometryN
        (
            ST_Intersection
            (
                buffers.extring, 
                buffers.geom2
            )
            , 1
        )
        AS point2,
        buffers.intersection,
        buffers.extring,
        buffers.geom1,
        buffers.geom2,
        buffers.id1,
        buffers.id2
    FROM 
        buffers
)
SELECT 
    points.point1,
    points.point2,
    points.extring,
    points.geom1,
    points.geom2,
    abs
    (
        round
        (
            degrees
            (
                ST_Azimuth
                (
                    points.point2,
                    points.intersection
                )
                -
                ST_Azimuth
                (
                    points.point1,
                    points.intersection
                )           
            )::decimal % 180.0
            ,2
        )
    )
    AS angle, 
    points.id1 AS id1, 
    points.id2 AS id2 
FROM 
    points
LIMIT 1000
;
ALTER TABLE angletmp ADD COLUMN id serial;
```

but I get this error : 
ERREUR:  Argument must be POINT geometries

I can't understand the origin of the error and I'm wondering if you could help me solve it

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's your ST_Azimuth call.  Both arguments need to be points.

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html

Check each sub query to make sure your points.point1, points.point2, and points.intersection are all returning points.

You could test with a

```
WITH ....
SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(points.point1) AS t1,  
    ST_GeometryType(points.point2) AS t2,
    ST_GeometryType(points.intersection) As t3
FROM points;
```

The above should output exactly one record and all fields should read ST_Point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I checked each query and the problem was on the first one where the intersection between lines returns strangely linestrings. I added a contition on the id to the query `a.id!=b.id` to prevent self matching yet the problem is still in there. So I'm making researches to know why do I get such a result in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The fixation of the problem is to calculate the centroid of the intersection when the result is a linestring, like described the following query

```
`   SELECT
    ST_Transform
    (
        (ST_Dump
        (
           ST_Centroid
            (
            ST_Intersection
            (
                a.geom, 
                b.geom
            )
        )).geom,
        3785
    )
    AS intersection`
```